# How can I use Joomla's Cache with my components view?

Tags: development, mvc, cache

As is typically the case with a CMS, the most hits occur while it is still "new".  I'd like to cache the page output the first time it is rendered for a given period as to reduce the heavy workload that is required to generate it.

I've been working from the [JCache](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JCache.html) documentation, and have the basic mechanics worked out as shown here:

```
$cache = JFactory::getCache('MyCache', '');
$cache->setCaching(true);
$cache->setLifeTime(86400);  //24 hours
$cache_id = 'MyCache_page_123';
$cached_page= $cache->get($cache_id);
if (!empty($cached_page)) {
    $the_page_output = $cached_page;
}else{
    $the_page_output = ...<div>the generated view HTML</div>....
    $cache->store($the_page_output, $cache_id);
}
// echo or return "$the_page_output"
```

I'm stuck trying to determine where I should create the cache, then the "sweet spot" to *use* that cache before all the work begins again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far Google-searches make me presume that **joomla caches your component automatically if you add `display(true,...)` to your controller's display method** as in following example. 
The example also includes some measurement code to check if it's working (JProfiler part).

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array()) {
    $profiler = new JProfiler();//debug

    //Joomla cache only takes format, option, view, layout, tpl, language en id als default cache_id ($urlparams)
    $input  = new Jinput;
    $urlparams['comp_page_specific_id']=$input->getUInt('comp_specific_id');
    $urlparams['comp_page_specific_else']=$input->getUInt('comp_page_specific_else');

    parent::display(true, $urlparams);
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($profiler->mark( ' seconds with caching<br>Only works after someone has visited this page at least once.<br>Can be reset in backend.' ));//debug
}
```

- You have to **manually set the `$urlparams`** which define which component views need a different cache (**urlparams = cache_id** so to speak). And Joomla already takes care of common parameters such as format, option, view, layout, tpl, language en id.
- Also be aware that **no updates** will be done in your component. If you have a hit counter in your model, the **number of hits will stay constant** when a cached view is shown.

*Extra info: In joomla library's controller, it's the following line that calls the view cache and at the same time sets the cache if it wasn't yet:

    `$cache->get($view, 'display');  //689: legacy controller`

*(**EDIT** 2015-01-14: Added urlparams)*
*(**EDIT** 2015-01-15: Added code extra info)*

Comment: `but I can't find any core joomla code where the cache is being set.`
Just a note - it is inside `$cache->get` method

Comment: Wow! That's very clever coding.  Thanks for the info. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Just to be sure the answer is full, [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/cache/controller/view.php#L109) it is