# Cache works for html view but not for xml output

Tags: cache, xml, cache-handler

I'm currently debugging (and trying to understand why) the caching for the html view is created, but not for the xml view.

I read the Joomla! documentation article https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_Cache
and a similiar question in this portal 5 years ago: [How can I use Joomla's Cache with my components view?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/how-can-i-use-joomlas-cache-with-my-components-view)

My `controller.php` looks like this:

```
public function display($cacheable = false, $urlparams = false)
{
    $cacheable = true;

    $viewName   = $this->input->get('view');
    $viewLayout = $this->input->get('layout', 'default');

    if (JFactory::getUser()->get('id') || !in_array($viewName, array('html', 'xml')) || $viewLayout == 'xsl') {
        $cacheable = false;
    }

    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $viewType = $document->getType();

    $view = $this->getView($viewName, $viewType, '', array('base_path' => $this->basePath, 'layout' => $viewLayout));

    $view->setModel($this->getModel('Sitemap'), true);

    $safeurlparams = array(
        'id' => 'INT',
        'itemid' => 'INT',
        'uid' => 'CMD',
        'action' => 'CMD',
        'property' => 'CMD',
        'value' => 'CMD',
        'view' => 'CMD',
        'lang' => 'CMD'
    );

    return parent::display($cacheable, $safeurlparams);
}
```

Folder structure:
components
- com_my_extension
--- views
---- html
---- xml

What I am missing here?

Is it that the standard Joomla! cache, doesn't cache the XML output and I have to do it manually?

Or is the data in `$safeurlparams` wrong? (I don't totally understand how the parts in this array should be.)

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448077/how-to-cache-a-php-generated-xml-file-in-joomla

An older question, but may give you a direction to consider to figure out what to add into the code generating your XML.

Comment: Thx for the link. If I interpret it right, the html view is automatically created with the controller display cachable true statement, but for XML I have to implement it on my own.

Comment: I think that sounds about right. I'm in the process of figuring out how various Joomla framework parts work currently, so if I find a different way of doing it, I'll comment back.

Comment: little more research. The cache should be made with the existing code. Something is preventing the cache file to be created for the second view. Still debugging which part is the barrier.